# Handling one-to-many references in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-normalization

I didn't know how to give title to this but I have the following database:

```
accidentDetain(id, location, weather_conditions desc (and few more columns));
weatherConditions(id, title)
acc_weat_cond(id, wc_id, ad_id)
wc_id = weatherConditions ID, ad_id = accidentDetain ID
```

Now the situation is the user can store multiple weather conditions such as (rain, wet, snow Ice Fog etc)

Let's say user chooses 3 out of those 6 options and those will be stored in `acc_weat_cond` table, with accident Detail id and weather conditions id.

After saving, the user decided to change and to unchecked one of the option and then presses the save button. The issue is, there are 3 records already stored into **`acc_weat_cond`** table how would I would change and make them to two records.

Will I have to delete the first records from the database and then store again newly checked options? Or is there any easier way doing the above mentioned situation.

One last option is that I violate the role of database normalization and stored directly in the accidentDetails table and separate the values with a comma.

Feel free to ask if any more information is required...

Comment: **Please note:** User can come anytime in the future and change those values and save again. Not necessarily updating straight away as if he have made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an `<input type='hidden'name='checkedflds' value='1,2,3' />`-field which contained the values  that were checked before the user updated. Then after postback, you can compare the new list against this and will easily see what additions he made and which elements he removed...

Comment: That leaves an opening for bad data to get in.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I'm spoiled (I have only have 'serious' non-hacking users in an intranet-app). But what do you mean with `call all of the options`? Query the database again? That might have an impact on performance. What about storing that infomration in $_SESSION?

Answer (score 0):

I would call all of the options and compare to what is checked, and delete what you need. If you store it on the form, then there is a potential for out of date data.